Are Bitcoin related questions welcome here?
I'm considering applying Quant. Finance models to Bitcoin, an anonymous bank-free cryptographic currency, and incorporating that into my Master's Thesis.
With that being said, what types of Q&A would be welcome here that relates to Bitcoin?

a posteriori did any questions show up?

If your question is something like asset pricing, volatility, or hedging, then it could be very interesting. If your question is about BitCoin itself, then the BitCoin.SE would be ideal (I notice you've posted on there before, so you're likely familiar with the types of questions they expect).

I just posted my Q.. let me know what you think....
